# Циклический сдвиг

Tags: c

Циклический сдвиг. Функция без оглашенних параметров. Задание: циклический сдвиг влево

```
void zmischennya(int *masuv, int n,...)
{
     int *mas,j,temp;
     mas=masuv;
     printf("\n Zmischennuy masuv:\n");
     for (j=1; j<=n; j++)
     {
         *mas=*(mas+j);
         *(mas+n)=*(mas-(n-1));
         printf("\t %i",*mas);
     }
     getch();
}
```

Никак не могу вывести последнего значения, которое было первым (а точнее нулевым).
Что я неправильно делаю???

Comment: Наверное, потому что обмен значений идет не через временную переменную. `temp` - неиспользована!!!

Comment: 1. Зачем mas?

2. Первый индекс == 0

3. Сдвиг на одну позицию? Как писал @gecube, где temp?

    for(j=0; j < n; j++) {
      temp = masuv[j];
      j1 = (j + 1) % n;
      masuv[j] = masuv[j1];
      masuv[j1] = temp;
   }

Можно и без temp (через "исключающе или")

Comment: @dark8eider, если хотите подойти к этому вопросу серьезно, то можете ознакомится с тремя алгоритмами [Циклический сдвиг одномерного массива или строки](http://codelab.ru/task/cycle_shift/).

Comment: Блин, второпях не учёл, что temp надо присваивать только один раз

    temp = masuv[0];
    for(j=1; j < n; j++) masuv[j-1] = masuv[j];
    masuv[n-1] = temp;

Answer (score 3):

Смотрите.

Вы должны 1-ый элемент записать на место 0-го, затем 2-й -- на место 1-го, и так далее. Затем на место последнего -- 0-ой. Чтобы этот самый 0-ой не потерялся на начальном шаге, его стоит сохранить во временную переменную.

А что делаете вы? На `j`-ом шаге вы записываете `j`-ый элемент на место 0-го. То есть подряд все элементы записываете в нулевой. Это уже неправильно, так ведь?

Дальше совсем катастрофа: `*(mas-(n-1))` -- это же элемент с индексом `-(n-1)`, то есть `1-n`! Такого элемента в массиве нету, то есть вы попадаете в случайную область памяти. Затем, `*(mas+n)` тоже неверно: в `n`-элементном массиве индексы от 0 до `n-1`. Поэтому, кстати, цикл стоит делать не до `n`, а всего лишь до `n-1`.

Стало яснее?

Comment: Большое спасибо. Наконец то все понял.